# Telr Payment integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to integrate Telr Payment integration in my App, I have gone through the DOC part and it seems like   I have to request for enabling mobile API. If anyone has a demo of Telr integration in iOS, please feel free to share it. I am unable  to find any demo regarding this Telr payment integration.

I am giving you my demo but Every time I am getting error and it says type -"**E**" Code-**01**. If any one here has any idea please help me out. Actually I am making a testing demo and it may be possible that I am passing some wrong params but in actual I don't know which params are wrong.

```
NSString *paramString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"

                      "<mobile:Body>\n"
                      "<store>%@</store>"
                      "<key>%@</key>"

                      "<device:Body>\n"
                      "<type>%@</type>"
                      "<id>%@</id>"
                      "<agent>%@</agent>"
                      "<accept>%@</<accept>"
                      "</device:Body>\n"

                      "<app:Body>\n"
                      "<name>%@</name>"
                      "<version>%@</version>"
                      "<user>%@</user>"
                      "<id>%@</<id>"
                      "</app:Body>\n"

                      "<tran:Body>\n"
                      "<test>%@</test>"
                      "<type>%@</type>"
                      "<class>%@</class>"
                      "<cartid>%@</<cartid>"
                      "<description>%@</description>"
                      "<currency>%@</currency>"
                      "<amount>%@</amount>"
                      "<ref>%@</<ref>"
                      "</tran:Body>\n"
                      "</mobile:Body>\n"
                         ,@"123",@"XG32K#rBLn~BSm82",@"Simulator",@"xyzabc",@"",@"",@"Telr-Payment-Demo",@"1.0",@"Syscraft.Telr-Payment-Demo",@"",@"Test mode",@"PAYPAGE",@"",@"123",@"hello",@"AED",@"9.50",@""];


NSString *requestURL=@"https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/mobile.xml";

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL];
NSData *data=[paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *mRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[mRequest setURL:url];

[mRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];




[mRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[mRequest setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [mRequest setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData1  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];



if (error!=nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Webservice Error==%@",error);
}
else
{
    NSString *responseDic =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData1 options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error!=nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Webservice Error==%@",error);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"responseDic ======\n %@",responseDic);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did u find the answer?

Comment: Why u are using :Body in almost all tags that is not required

Comment: @iOS_Developer Yes I have found the answer. Actually I am not very friendly to XML. Hence don't know how to send paramters using XML. YOu have said the right thing, I have corrected the the XML structure and it is running fine . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: me too working on it, requests are being sent and received successfully,
will soon post my complete findings here so that it helps others

Comment: Can you please update your question with your updated request ? And do tell how you are handling the response. Thanks.

Comment: Also is there any URL to show the Telr Payment gateway on a Web View, how you are invoking it ?

Comment: @AmmadKhan yes it is already provided on the documention. https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/mobile.xml. This is the URL

Comment: @Prakash,  Can you please update your working request ? - Thanks

Comment: @Ammad Khan ..What do you want? what working request you are talking about???

Comment: Your **paramString** has **:Body**, I wanted to see the working **paramString**, anyways Thanks. I will sort it out.

Comment: @AmmadKhan https://github.com/PrakashGupta123/TelrPayment_Demo_iOS . Here is the full link please download the proj andmodify acc to your needs

Comment: Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: @AmmadKhan welcome brother. Don't forget brothers look after each other. Happy coding buddy;-)

Comment: @AmmadKhan please let me know if u have successfully implemented the code ok??

Comment: I have done same thing as provided by your demo but i am getting<mobile>
 <webview>
<start>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_start.html? code=f1caa6ce6c23595b71dc00369</start>   
<close>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_close.html</close>
<abort>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_abort.html</abort>
<code>f1caa6ce6c23595b71dc00369</code>
</webview>
<trace>40008/1683846/595b7168dc</trace>
</mobile> instead of authorized response. What should i do to get authorized response

Comment: @sarojraut, You have to put secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_start.htm‌​l? code=f1caa6ce6c23595b71dc00369 in your webview from there u will get the authorised response.

Comment: @sarojraut Don't forgot to accept my answer if it really worked for u.

Comment: Hi, @Prakash this xml is not working and also how i will enter card number , i want to test with dummy card number. I am implementing in obj c

Comment: I am getting error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: @prakashand : ___ <message>Email not valid/not supplied</message> :  i give the email field but it still give me that error if i remove the email then still show me the error and on the portal the source is Payment Page (V2)

Comment: After this we have to pass received code in webview to "https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/mobile_complete.xml", but after hitting this I am getting an error as <code>01</code>\n    <message>Invalid request</message> (Test mode)